# Documents not being stored in full in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am working on a project for a client.  This project consists of multiple pages of form inputs that are used as an online application.  I am using NodeJS and MongoDB for server communication and storage.  The online applications that are submitted are stored in MongoDB as individual documents.

The problem I am having is around 8% of these applications are not being stored completely.  There are 162 inputs in the application.  For some reason this 8% of the applications are only storing the initial input value which is the email address.  The rest of the inputs are blank.  If there was a problem in the javascript, would that not affect all of the entries and not just 8% or so?

My initial thinking was that this is user error and the applicants aren't getting passed the initial page, but the client has informed me that they are receiving mailed paperwork that is only accessible to print if the applicant completes the online application in full.  This leads me to believe that MongoDB is the culprit.  I just don't know how I can prove this.  Could insufficient processing power on the server cause this kind of intermittent issue?  I am using an Amazon AWS m1 Small instance for this project, which is fairly inexpensive and less powerful, but there are only just over 1,200 documents in the database over a 3 month span, so the server isn't being hit very hard at all.

Has anyone else ran into such a problem?  Any suggestions you all may have on the topic would be appreciated.  As it stands, I don't know where to go from here to correct this problem.

Comment: One thought would be to monitor incoming messages to mongod via a network sniffing tool (Wireshark for example). Seeing the actual data sent would help confirm whether the write requests contain this data. If I had to guess though it would be that the issue is upstream of MongoDB, either in the driver or client application.

Comment: I am pretty new to all of this and this is actually my first real client.  Do you have any tips for how to go about setting up wireshark to sniff?  I have never used it.  And if the issue is upstream of MongoDB, what can I do to resolve this?

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is specific to a particular browser? You can store  the browser user-agent along with the form data to see if this is the case.

Comment: The browser and version are being saved in the documents.  The documents that are missing form inputs came from all different browsers.  The first two entries that are missing data were submitted with IE10 and Safari.

Comment: Maybe certain input values are breaking the form?

Comment: You mean what people are entering into the fields?  I guess that is a possibility, but I don't really see that as the cause.  The more I look into this issue, the more I believe that MongoDB is at fault here.  This article http://hackingdistributed.com/2013/01/29/mongo-ft/ has given me a lot to think about in regards to MongoDB.